# New colum in pandas, based on another column's last value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

In the dataframe I got this data

```
                     Open        High         Low       Close   Volume  \
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date                                                                  
2015-05-01  538.429993  539.539978  532.099976  537.900024  1768200   
2015-05-04  538.530029  544.070007  535.059998  540.780029  1308000   
2015-05-05  538.210022  539.739990  530.390991  530.799988  1383100   
2015-05-06  531.239990  532.380005  521.085022  524.219971  1567000
```

My question is: how do I add a new column and give it a value of 0 if the last close was lower that the present close and 1 if it is higher.

How do I make this work through out the dataframe?

Comment: What value should be assigned if the values are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df['increasing'] = (df['Open'].diff() > 0).astype(int)
```

or

```
df['increasing'] = (df['Open'] - df['Open'].shift() > 0).astype(int)
```

both work, but the former is quicker.

---

Take, for example,

```
In [41]: import pandas_datareader.data as pdata

In [42]: df = pdata.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', start='2009-01-02', end='2009-12-31')

In [43]: df.head()
Out[43]: 
                 Open       High        Low      Close     Volume  Adj Close
Date                                                                        
2009-01-02  85.880003  91.040001  85.160000  90.750001  186503800  11.933430
2009-01-05  93.170003  96.179998  92.709999  94.580002  295402100  12.437067
2009-01-06  95.950000  97.170001  92.389998  93.020000  322327600  12.231930
2009-01-07  91.809999  92.500001  90.260003  91.010000  188262200  11.967619
2009-01-08  90.430000  93.150002  90.039998  92.699999  168375200  12.189851
```

`diff()` returns the difference between adjacent rows:

```
In [45]: df['Open'].diff().head()
Out[45]: 
Date
2009-01-02         NaN
2009-01-05    7.290000
2009-01-06    2.779997
2009-01-07   -4.140001
2009-01-08   -1.379999
Name: Open, dtype: float64
```

`(df['Open'].diff() > 0)` returns a boolean-valued Series which is True when the difference is positive:

```
In [46]: (df['Open'].diff() > 0).head()
Out[46]: 
Date
2009-01-02    False
2009-01-05     True
2009-01-06     True
2009-01-07    False
2009-01-08    False
Name: Open, dtype: bool
```

Calling `.astype(int)` converts False to 0 and True to 1:

```
In [47]: (df['Open'].diff() > 0).astype('int').head()
Out[47]: 
Date
2009-01-02    0
2009-01-05    1
2009-01-06    1
2009-01-07    0
2009-01-08    0
Name: Open, dtype: int64
```

---

The code becomes a bit more complicated if you need to assign 
a third possible value, 2, when the difference is 0:

```
import numpy as np
diff = df['Open'].diff()
conditions = [diff > 0, diff < 0]
choices = [1, 0]
df['increasing'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=2)
```

[`np.select`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) is a generalization of `np.where`. `np.where` is good for handling 1 condition, `np.select` handles multiple conditions. Above, the conditions are `diff > 0` and `diff < 0` and we wish to assign the values 1 and 0, respectively:

```
conditions = [diff > 0, diff < 0]
choices = [1, 0]
```

When neither condition is True, `np.select` assigns the default value 2:

```
df['increasing'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=2)
```

Comment: im kinda confused, can you please explain what the first one does thank you

Comment: thank you soo much, that made a lot fo sense . Thanks once again